# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Chart: (?, ?) in Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2, chart.js

I have implemented chart in my ionic2 application. But when I try to run the application, I am getting an error `Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Chart: (?, ?)` . Could you please help me with this issue? I have used `chart.js` library.

### Code

```
export class ChartPage {
  @ViewChild('barCanvas') barCanvas:ElementRef;     
  barChart: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

  this.barChart = new Chart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement, {

      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero:true
                  }
              }]
          }
      }

  });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the declaration of 'chart.js' from the app.module.ts file to solve the error